# qt app with opencv fails at shutdown (0xC000004B)

Tags: c++, qt, dll, opencv

Simple qt(4.7.3) and opencv(2.3.1) app running under debug in vs2008 terminates with messages:

```
...
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2418) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1cc4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xd7c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2108) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x17a0) has exited with code -1073741749 (0xc000004b).
The program '[472] QtArrSurf.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

0xC000004B error code means STATUS_THREAD_IS_TERMINATING (An attempt was made to suspend a thread that has begun termination).

Program source code:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton b("button");
    b.show();
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(&b, "Dialog", "", "Files(*.png)"); // problem trigger
    cv::SURF detectorSURF;    // just to touch opencv
    return a.exec();
}
```

If comment dialog everything goes smoothly without 0xc000004b and there is only one thread in program.
When dialog is executed a number of threads are spawned, which does not close with dialog:

```
0 > 6192    Main Thread Main Thread main    Normal  0
0   8928    Worker Thread   Win32 Thread    77a01f36    Normal  0
0   4620    Worker Thread   Win32 Thread    77a01f36    Normal  0
0   9800    Worker Thread   Win32 Thread    77a01f36    Normal  0
0   7924    Worker Thread   Win32 Thread    77a0014d    Normal  0
0   3844    Worker Thread   Win32 Thread    77a01f36    Normal  0
0   2524    RPC Thread  RPC Callback Thread 779ffd81    Normal  0
0   3068    Worker Thread   Win32 Thread    77a00552    Normal  0
...
```

What these threads are about?
They have silent stacks, like this:

> ntdll.dll!77a01f36()
>           [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
>           ntdll.dll!77a01f36()
>           ntdll.dll!77a2471e()
>           kernel32.dll!7587339a()
>           ntdll.dll!77a19ed2()
>           ntdll.dll!77a19ea5()

The place of interest is CvModule static object in opencv dll.
OpenCV\2.3.1\modules\core\src\system.cpp:

```
 CvModule cxcore_module( &cxcore_info );
```

In fail case i do not reach its destructor, but in good (without dialog) do.

Is this situation with 0xC000004B real problem?

Any suggestion where to look for solution?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use official prebuilt OpenCV binaries from sourceforge, then you are seeing TBB threads.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your app is not failing.

The exit code of a thread can be anything, a non zero return value from a thread does not indicate an error, it just indicates that the thread returned that value when it exited, for whatever reason.

Unless you are experiencing a crash or some other problem on exit I think you can safely ignore that non zero return value. If you want to fully understand why the thread returns this value you will need to debug the QT code and determine which thread is doing this. If you find the thread you could put a breakpoint at its exit point, to see why the logic in this function decided to return this value.